# I can't seem to grasp how to use a radial basis function kernel for a classification task in python

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, classification, kernel-density

I'm tasked with using Parzen windows with the radial basis function kernel to determine which label to give to a given point.

My training data set has 4 dimensions (4 features per point).
My training label set contains the labels (which can be 0,1,2,... depending on how many classes we have) for all the points in my training set (It's a 1D-array).
My test data set contains a couple of points with 4 dimensions but no labels so it's a nx4 array.

We're interested in giving labels for each of the points in my test data set.

I first compute the rdf kernel $k(x_i,x)$: (using python and numpy)

```
for (i, ex) in enumerate(test_data):

    squared_distances = (np.sum((np.abs(ex - self.train_inputs)) ** 2, axis=1)) ** (1.0 / 2)
    k = np.exp(- squared_distances/2*(np.square(self.sigma)))
```

Let's assume that `test_data` looks like this :

```
[[  0.40614   1.3492   -1.4501   -0.55949]
 [ -1.3887   -4.8773    6.4774    0.34179]
 [ -3.7503  -13.4586   17.5932   -2.7771 ]
 [ -3.5637   -8.3827   12.393    -1.2823 ]
 [ -2.5419   -0.65804   2.6842    1.1952 ]]
```

`ex` is a point from the test data set. here as an example :

```
[ 0.40614  1.3492  -1.4501  -0.55949]
```

`self.train_inputs` is the training data set and it looks like this

```
[[ 3.6216   8.6661  -2.8073  -0.44699]
 [ 4.5459   8.1674  -2.4586  -1.4621 ]
 [ 3.866   -2.6383   1.9242   0.10645]
 ...
 [-1.1667  -1.4237   2.9241   0.66119]
 [-2.8391  -6.63    10.4849  -0.42113]
 [-4.5046  -5.8126  10.8867  -0.52846]]
```

`k` is an array containing all the distances between every x_i (in self.training_inputs) and our current test point x (which is `ex` in the code).

```
k = [0.99837982 0.9983832  0.99874063 ... 0.9988909  0.99706044 0.99698724]
```

It's of the same length as the number of points in `self.train_inputs`.

My understanding of the radial basis function is that the closest the training points are to the test point the greater the value of k(current training point, test point). However `k` can never exceed 1 or be below 0.

So the goal is to select the training point that is the closest to the test point. We do this by looking which has the greatest value in `k`. Then we take its index and use that same index on the array containing the labels only. Therefore we get the label we want our test point to take.

In code it translates to this (the additional code is put below the first code snippet above) :

```
best_arg = np.argmax(k) #selects the greatest value in k and gives back its index.
classes_pred[i] = self.train_labels[best_arg] #we use the index to select the label in the train labels array.
```

Here `self.train_labels` looks like :

```
[0. 0. 0. ... 1. 1. 1.]
```

This approach gives for `ex = [ 0.40614  1.3492  -1.4501  -0.55949]`  and `k = [0.99837982 0.9983832  0.99874063 ... 0.9988909  0.99706044 0.99698724]` :

`818` for the index containing the greatest value in the current `k` and `1.` as the label given `self.train_labels[818] = 1.`

However it seems that I'm doing this wrong. Given an already implemented algorithm by my teacher I get some of the labels wrong (especially when we have more then two classes). My question is am I doing this wrong? If yes where? I'm new to machine learning btw.